# python - is it possible to catch and handle exception raised by library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using external library, that raises exception in case of HTTPError:

```
if r.status_code != 200:
    raise HTTPError(r.text)
```

I would like to somehow handle this exception in my code, in a way it does not break the script execution but, logs the error and continue.
Is it possible without changing the external library itself?
Something like:

```
except: HTTPError as e:
...
   pass
```

I want to override how the exception is originally handled in the lib.

Comment: I think the only way in which you can do this is by using a try-catch block

Comment: yes, but HTTPError is not a standard excepton so I would need to somehow import this exception from external library as well?

Comment: "Continue" where…? At the point where the exception was thrown, continuing as if it wasn't thrown? Well, no, you can't do that. The code raises the exception because it asserts it can't continue as is, because certain preconditions aren't met. You can't force it to continue nonetheless.

Comment: @Wojtas.Zet Yes, you'll need to import that exception class from that library.

Comment: yes I want to override default behaviour, how this exception is handled by the lib

Comment: Yes, you would need to import that exception. If it's a sensibly designed library, it'll make that available for import. You could just generically catch `Exception`, but you should narrow that down to the specific exception you expect if at all possible.

Comment: @deceze continue to the next iteration of the loop of main () (which is inside try block)

Comment: Then you're nesting your `try` block wrong? You want it inside the loop, not outside it. `for ...: try: library_call() except HTTPError: continue`

Comment: Guys it works perfectly fine after importing the external exception :-) That was the key, I never did it before. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can catch the error

```py
class HTTPError(Exception):
    pass

try:
    # suppose you are doing some action that raises HTTPError
    raise HTTPError()

except HTTPError as e:
    # catch the error
    print('http error')

finally:
    print('closing')
```

```
http error
closing
```

Remember you need to import the non-standard exception class.